# Ошибки в пути к картинке, как исправить

Tags: java

У меня есть отдельный файл с картинками под названием src, в котором файл img и там картинки.
Файл Src я назначил права Resources Root. Но ошибка не пропала.

Код:

```
package company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import sweeper.Box;
import sweeper.Coord;
import sweeper.Game;
import sweeper.Ranges;

public class JavaSweeper extends JFrame
{
    private Game game;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;

    private final int COLS = 9; // столбцы
    private final int ROWS = 9; // строки
    private final int BOMBS = 10; // количество бомб
    private final int IMAGE_SIZE = 30; // размер картинки одинаковый по x и по y
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        new JavaSweeper();
    }

    private JavaSweeper ()
    {
        game = new Game(COLS, ROWS, BOMBS);
        game.start();
        setImages();
        initLabel();
        initPanel();
        initFrame();
    }

    private void initLabel ()
    {
        label = new JLabel("Найди все бомбы!!!");
        add (label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void initPanel (){
        panel = new JPanel() // при инициализации выводим картинки
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                for (Coord coord : Ranges.getAllCoords())
                    //g.drawImage((Image) game.getBox(coord).image, coord.x * IMAGE_SIZE, coord.y * IMAGE_SIZE, this); //приведение типа к Image
                    g.drawImage((Image) game.getBox(coord).image, coord.x * IMAGE_SIZE, coord.y * IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, this); //приведение типа к Image

            }
        };

        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = e.getX() / IMAGE_SIZE;
                int y = e.getY() / IMAGE_SIZE;
                Coord coord = new Coord(x, y);
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) // левая кнопка мыши
                    game.pressLeftButton (coord);
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) // правая кнока мыши
                    game.pressRightButton (coord);
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) // средняя кнопка мыши
                    game.start (); // перезапускаем игру
                label.setText(getessage ());
                panel.repaint(); // после каждого действия мыши перерисовываем панель игры
            }
        });

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Ranges.getSize().x * IMAGE_SIZE, Ranges.getSize().y * IMAGE_SIZE));
        add (panel);
    }

    private String getessage()
    {
        switch (game.getState())
        {
            case PLAYED: return "Еще есть бомбы";
            case BOMBED:return "Бабах - ты взорвался";
            case WINNER: return "Примите поздравления";
            default: return "Welcome";
        }
    }

    private void initFrame ()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Java Sweeper 2000 Volosatov");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        pack(); //метод из класса JFrame устанавливает размер окна достаточный для отображения
        setIconImage(getImage("icon"));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    private void setImages ()
    {
        for (Box box : Box.values())
            box.image = getImage(box.name().toLowerCase());
    }

    private Image getImage (String name){
        String filename = "img/" + name + ".png";
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename)); //использование ресурсов (подключить папку с ресурсами)
        return icon.getImage();

    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибки не из-за картинок. Тебе нужно узнать, что такое NullPointerException.  Хотя бы на этом сайте, тут полно вопросов на эту тему.

Comment: Добавьте вывод `getClass().getResource(filename)`, думаю там будет `null`

Comment: Да, так и есть, там выводит null. Мне нужно понять как исправить это. Как я понимаю - он не видит файлы.

Comment: @Blacit, а попробуйте так `"/img/" + name + ".png"`

Comment: Спасибо большое, можно закрывать топик, вот правильный ответ: "/img/" + name + ".png"

Comment: @gil9red Можете свой комментарий занести в ответ, отмечу его правильным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина ошибки в том, что `getClass().getResource(filename)` возвращал `null`.

Другими словами ресурс по указанному адресу не был найден.

Попробуйте строить путь к ресурсу, начиная с слеша:

```
String filename = "/img/" + name + ".png";
```